# Kendo UI trim input

Tags: input, kendo-ui, trim

Is there a way of triming Kendo UI web input fields after the control loose focus ? Or before the viewmodel submit to the server ? I would like to prevent white space at the begining and end of string values.

Comment: Are you using a kendo data source?  Is this on an editable grid or just on a form with data bound controls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used JQuery to do it. Like this : `$("#myForm input").val("");`